# Importing PostGIS polygon to Esri has negative area and results in null geometry?

Tags: arcpy, postgis, arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms

I have data in PostgreSQL with PostGIS that seems fine. I am trying to 'copy' that in to ESRI ArcGIS. I have 4 test rows, 3 import fine. I've also modified a jsfiddle that I found and now has the problem polygon at http://jsfiddle.net/bryanm/nev4hgvo/

```
fieldnames= ['SHAPE@']
sql = """select st_asbinary(geom),st_astext(geom)
        from asset_utm.dareport_misc
        """
cur.execute(sql)
val = cur.fetchone()
spatRef = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)
while val != None:
    geom = arcpy.FromWKB(bytearray(val[0]),spatRef)
    geom = arcpy.FromWKT(val[1],spatRef)
    logger.info("Type {0} points {1} parts {2} length{3} area {4}"
                .format(geom.type, geom.pointCount, geom.partCount, geom.length, geom.area ))
    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor( 'VEGDBO.TRAIL_PY',fieldnames) as iCur:
        iCur.insertRow([geom])
    val = cur.fetchone()
```

The results from the logging are:

```
2017-07-05 12:24:40,173 - INFO - Type polygon points 20 parts 1 length0.00480354599632 area 1.30829909172e-06
2017-07-05 12:24:40,173 - INFO - Type polygon points 12 parts 1 length0.00575032905258 area 2.10941832519e-06
2017-07-05 12:24:40,188 - INFO - Type polygon points 114 parts 1 length0.00965835903742 area 5.79334045003e-06
2017-07-05 12:24:40,188 - INFO - Type polygon points 58 parts 0 length0.0137069668581 area -9.77088097695e-06
```

The last row with the -9x10^-6 area is null in the oracle sde based feature. I copied the table into a file geodatabase then ran check geometry, which said it was null.

Other tips I tried was buffering the values by 1 and 0 but that seemed to make things worse - the other geometries became null. I also tried st_simplify with a really small number (0.0000001) but that didn't resolve the issue either - with a larger number I just ended up with 4 points.

First of all, I don't currently know that it is converted to null when I insert it. I've googled for a way to find in arcpy that it is not going to happy.

Is there a better way to check for this than checking for negative area?

Secondly, any idea why this is happening, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Negative area is an indication that your polygon is wound incorrectly.  Please experiment with `ST_IsValid()` and `ST_MakeValid()` in the database before trying to get ArcGIS to accept the polygons.

Comment: Thanks @Vince, I already tried st_isvalid() and all the rows came back as valid. I have now tried st_makevalid and it doesn't change anything. I also wrote directly into a file geodatabase; not surprisingly, it didn't make any differences either.

Comment: With further testing, I can create a geometry from this problem set of points. I can insert into a new fgdb. Check Geometry shows no errors. I can then append to the sde feature. This now shows up, albeit with adjusted points, here's a [picture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8_s7Orw2GMhT003ak9CRHJ4TVU/view?usp=sharing), the green is the original from the fgdb, the orange is from the Oracle sde.
The strange thing is that I cannot insert it into another fgdb that has essentially the same definition for that feature (both wgs84 / srid 4326), but also other tables that have no geometries.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any additional information that may help to make it more answerable.